# How to test IPN from website with the new Paypal Sandbox?

Tags: paypal, simulation, sandbox, paypal-ipn

I used to use the old PayPal sandbox to simulate a payment using IPN (posting a payment, and then confirming the IPN).  This used to work fine with the classic sandbox.

With the introduction of the new Sandbox - I try to submit the request as I used to (redirecting the user to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?) which should take the user to the payment page - but this link now takes the user to the logon page for the sandbox.
Is this no longer supported?

I see there is still an IPN simulator, but I want to test the end-to-end round trip process from the user-perspective.  This does not seem possible anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try clearing your cache and cookies prior to opening up the developer.paypal.com site and logging in.  Also try using Firefox or Chrome if you are using Internet Explorer.

Comment: I retried using IE after clearing cookies and it is working as before now.